# Get the identity token from Azure AD Connect

Tags: c#, azure, asp.net-core, identityserver4

I am trying to find out how can I get the Identity Token from the azure ad connect. I am integrating it with Identity Server 4 (dotnet core). Their sample shows how to connect AD with Identity Server but I can't find how actually get the Id Token. I've also tried accessing it using the events but had no success. This is my configuration on Startup.cs on the identity server project.

```
 public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, 
 ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
{
    loggerFactory.AddConsole(LogLevel.Debug);
        app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();

        app.UseIdentityServer();

        app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
        {
            AuthenticationScheme = IdentityServerConstants.ExternalCookieAuthenticationScheme,

            AutomaticAuthenticate = false,
            AutomaticChallenge = false
        });

        ///
        /// Setup Custom Data Format
        /// 
        var schemeName = "oidc";
        var dataProtectionProvider = app.ApplicationServices.GetRequiredService<IDataProtectionProvider>();
        var distributedCache = app.ApplicationServices.GetRequiredService<IDistributedCache>();

        var dataProtector = dataProtectionProvider.CreateProtector(
            typeof(OpenIdConnectMiddleware).FullName,
            typeof(string).FullName, schemeName,
            "v1");

        var dataFormat = new CachedPropertiesDataFormat(distributedCache, dataProtector);

        ///
        /// Azure AD Configuration
        /// 
        var clientId = "XXXX";
        var tenantId = "XXXXX";

        app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(new OpenIdConnectOptions
        {
            AuthenticationScheme = schemeName,
            DisplayName = "AzureAD",
            SignInScheme = IdentityServerConstants.ExternalCookieAuthenticationScheme,
            ClientId = clientId,
            Authority = $"https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenantId}",
            ResponseType = OpenIdConnectResponseType.IdToken,
            StateDataFormat = dataFormat,
            Events = new OpenIdConnectEvents
            {
                OnRemoteFailure = OnAuthenticationFailed,
                OnTokenValidated = OnTokenValidated,
                OnTokenResponseReceived = TokenResponseReceived
            },
            TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
            {
                SaveSigninToken = true
            }
        });

        app.UseStaticFiles();
          app.UseMvcWithDefaultRoute();
 }
```

These are my event handlers from which I hoped to get the id token.

```
private Task OnTokenValidated(TokenValidatedContext context)
    {
        var type = context.Properties.GetType();
        var tokens = context.Properties.GetTokens();
        var ci = (System.Security.Claims.ClaimsIdentity)
         ClaimsPrincipal.Current.Identity;
        return Task.FromResult(0);
    }

    private Task OnAuthenticationFailed(FailureContext context)
    {
        var failure = context.Failure;
        return Task.FromResult(0);
    }

    public Task TokenResponseReceived(TokenResponseReceivedContext context)
    {
        var variable = context.TokenEndpointResponse.IdToken;
        return Task.FromResult(0);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can read Token information under `context.SecurityToken`.

I use [my sample project](https://github.com/WinLwinOoNet/AspNetCoreAzureAD) as base, and add `OnTokenValidated` and `OnTokenResponseReceived`  to test it.

*(Click on the image to enlarge it)*
[image]

Comment: I need the Identity Token. The jwt string representing the identity. Even if they are the same, I still don't see that string I can retrieve from your example.